# Select values from dictionary to create a new DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary

```
type_dict = {3: 'foo', 4: 'bar',5: 'foobar', 6: 'foobarbar'}
```

and a DataFrame with the following column:

```
>>> df.type
0     3
1     4
2     5
3     6
4     3
5     4
6     5
7     6
8     3
```

I want to create a new column containing the corresponding `type_dict` value, but the following was the only thing I could come up and was not working:

```
>>> type_dict[df.type]
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

>>> type_dict[df.type.values]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Do I really need to `apply` and iterate through each row, or is there a more efficient alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) here:

```
>>> df['type'].map(type_dict)
0          foo
1          bar
2       foobar
3    foobarbar
4          foo
5          bar
6       foobar
7    foobarbar
8          foo
Name: type, dtype: object
```

`map` can take a dictionary, Series or function and return a new Series with the mapped values. It is also very efficiently implemented (much more so than `apply`, for example).

Comment: This worked, after switching `dtype` from `object` to `integer`.