# Find key from value for Pandas Series

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a dictionary whose values are in a pandas series. I want to make a new series that will look up a value in a series and return a new series with associated key. Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'season' : ['Nor 2014', 'Nor 2013', 'Nor 2013', 'Norv 2013',
                           'Swe 2014', 'Swe 2014',  'Swe 2013',
                           'Swe 2013', 'Sven 2013', 'Sven 2013', 'Norv 2014']})

nmdict = {'Norway' : [s for s in list(set(df.season)) if 'No' in s],
                  'Sweden' : [s for s in list(set(df.season)) if 'S' in s]}
```

Desired result with `df['country']` as the new column name:

```
       season country
0    Nor 2014  Norway
1    Nor 2013  Norway
2    Nor 2013  Norway
3   Norv 2013  Norway
4    Swe 2014  Sweden
5    Swe 2014  Sweden
6    Swe 2013  Sweden
7    Swe 2013  Sweden
8   Sven 2013  Sweden
9   Sven 2013  Sweden
10  Norv 2014  Norway
```

Due to nature of my data I must manually make the `nmdict` as shown. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312566/python-how-to-get-values-from-a-dictionary-from-pandas-series) but couldn't reverse my `nmdict` as arrays are not same length.

More importantly, I think my approach may be wrong. I'm coming from Excel and thinking of a vlookup solution, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary), I shouldn't be using the dictionary in this way.

Any answers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done it in a verbose manner to allow you to follow through.

First, let's define a function that determines the value 'country'

```
In [4]: def get_country(s):
   ...:     if 'Nor' in s:
   ...:         return 'Norway'
   ...:     if 'S' in s:
   ...:         return 'Sweden'
   ...:     # return 'Default Country' # if you get unmatched values

In [5]: get_country('Sven')
Out[5]: 'Sweden'

In [6]: get_country('Norv')
Out[6]: 'Norway'
```

We can use `map` to run `get_country` on every row. Pandas DataFrames also have a [`apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) which works similarly*.

```
In [7]: map(get_country, df['season'])
Out[7]: 
['Norway',
 'Norway',
 'Norway',
 'Norway',
 'Sweden',
 'Sweden',
 'Sweden',
 'Sweden',
 'Sweden',
 'Sweden',
 'Norway']
```

Now we assign that result to the column called 'country'

```
In [8]: df['country'] = map(get_country, df['season'])
```

Let's view the final result:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
       season country
0    Nor 2014  Norway
1    Nor 2013  Norway
2    Nor 2013  Norway
3   Norv 2013  Norway
4    Swe 2014  Sweden
5    Swe 2014  Sweden
6    Swe 2013  Sweden
7    Swe 2013  Sweden
8   Sven 2013  Sweden
9   Sven 2013  Sweden
10  Norv 2014  Norway
```

*With `apply()` here's how it would look:

```
In [16]: df['country'] = df['season'].apply(get_country)

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
       season country
0    Nor 2014  Norway
1    Nor 2013  Norway
2    Nor 2013  Norway
3   Norv 2013  Norway
4    Swe 2014  Sweden
5    Swe 2014  Sweden
6    Swe 2013  Sweden
7    Swe 2013  Sweden
8   Sven 2013  Sweden
9   Sven 2013  Sweden
10  Norv 2014  Norway
```

### A more *scalable* country matcher

pseudo-code only :)

```
# Modify this as needed
country_matchers = {
    'Norway': ['Nor', 'Norv'],
    'Sweden': ['S', 'Swed'], 
}

def get_country(s):
    """
    Run the passed string s against "matchers" for each country
    Return the first matched country
    """
    for country, matchers in country_matchers.items():
        for matcher in matchers:
            if matcher in s:
                return country
```

Comment: Thank you. One question, if I want to pass multiple OR conditions to return country, I tried `if 'Nor' in s or 'N' in s:` for line 2 of your `get_country` function. That works but is there a cleaner way to try an or (such as using | operator and many string 'snippets')? I have many OR conditions that may satisfy returning a particular country.

Comment: @noblerthanoedipus Added something you can modify easily without lots of tangled if/else/or etc

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, I would do the following:

```
df['country'] = df['season'].apply(lambda x: 'Norway' if 'No' in x else 'Sweden' if 'S' in x else x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create the country `dictionary` using a `dictionary comprehension`:

```
country_id = df.season.str.split().str.get(0).drop_duplicates()
country_dict = {c: ('Norway' if c.startswith('N') else 'Sweden') for c in country_id.values}
```

to get:

```
{'Nor': 'Norway', 'Swe': 'Sweden', 'Sven': 'Sweden', 'Norv': 'Norway'}
```

This works fine for two countries, otherwise you can `apply` a self-defined `function` in similar way:

```
def country_dict(country_id):
    if country_id.startswith('S'):
        return 'Sweden'
    elif country_id.startswith('N'):
        return 'Norway'
    elif country_id.startswith('XX'):
        return ...
    else:
        return 'default'
```

Either way, `map` the `dictionary` to the `country_id` part of the `season` `column`, extracted using `pandas` `string` methods:

```
df['country'] = df.season.str.split().str.get(0).map(country_dict)


       season country
0    Nor 2014  Norway
1    Nor 2013  Norway
2    Nor 2013  Norway
3   Norv 2013  Norway
4    Swe 2014  Sweden
5    Swe 2014  Sweden
6    Swe 2013  Sweden
7    Swe 2013  Sweden
8   Sven 2013  Sweden
9   Sven 2013  Sweden
10  Norv 2014  Norway
```